# How to change the item bullet to square given in the below image?

Tags: enumerate, itemize, labels, enumitem, renewcommand

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage[top=0.5in, bottom=0.5in, left=0.5in, right=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\square$}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\large \textbf{dkfksdjfksjflk}\\[0.1cm]
skdjfklsjfksjfslodsl $\mid 83748234799874 \mid$
\end{center}
\hrulefill\\[0.3cm]
\noindent \textbf{\underline {OBJECTIVE}}\\[0.3cm]
\noindent Graduate student looking for the position of Sales Manager in the company.\\[0.5cm]
\noindent \textbf{\underline{EDUCATION}}\\[0.3cm]
\noindent \textbf{\underline{EXPERIENCE}}\\[0.3cm]
\noindent Worked as Business Development intern in Innovators And You company where handling of the customers done effectively. Also managed the records of the customers properly.\\[0.3cm]
\noindent \textbf {\underline{SKILLS}}\\[0.3cm]
Excellent in communication and able to speak Hindi, English and Marathi languages. Having advance excel certification.\\[0.3cm]
\noindent \textbf {\underline{CERTIFICATIONS}}
\begin{itemize}
\item{Having MS-CIT certificate}
\item{Effective Listening}
\item{Communication Foundation}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You use `pifont` package with `\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{ >--symbol **\ding{113}** }`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage[top=0.5in, bottom=0.5in, left=0.5in, right=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{ \ding{113} }
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\large \textbf{dkfksdjfksjflk}\\[0.1cm]
skdjfklsjfksjfslodsl $\mid 83748234799874 \mid$
\end{center}
\hrulefill\\[0.3cm]
\noindent \textbf{\underline {OBJECTIVE}}\\[0.3cm]
\noindent Graduate student looking for the position of Sales Manager in the company.\\[0.5cm]
\noindent \textbf{\underline{EDUCATION}}\\[0.3cm]
\noindent \textbf{\underline{EXPERIENCE}}\\[0.3cm]
\noindent Worked as Business Development intern in Innovators And You company where handling of the customers done effectively. Also managed the records of the customers properly.\\[0.3cm]
\noindent \textbf {\underline{SKILLS}}\\[0.3cm]
Excellent in communication and able to speak Hindi, English and Marathi languages. Having advance excel certification.\\[0.3cm]
\noindent \textbf {\underline{CERTIFICATIONS}}
\begin{itemize}
\item{Having MS-CIT certificate}
\item{Effective Listening}
\item{Communication Foundation}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Otherwise `bbding` package with the symbol `\SquareShadowBottomRight`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage[top=0.5in, bottom=0.5in, left=0.5in, right=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{ \SquareShadowBottomRight }
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\large \textbf{dkfksdjfksjflk}\\[0.1cm]
skdjfklsjfksjfslodsl $\mid 83748234799874 \mid$
\end{center}
\hrulefill\\[0.3cm]
\noindent \textbf{\underline {OBJECTIVE}}\\[0.3cm]
\noindent Graduate student looking for the position of Sales Manager in the company.\\[0.5cm]
\noindent \textbf{\underline{EDUCATION}}\\[0.3cm]
\noindent \textbf{\underline{EXPERIENCE}}\\[0.3cm]
\noindent Worked as Business Development intern in Innovators And You company where handling of the customers done effectively. Also managed the records of the customers properly.\\[0.3cm]
\noindent \textbf {\underline{SKILLS}}\\[0.3cm]
Excellent in communication and able to speak Hindi, English and Marathi languages. Having advance excel certification.\\[0.3cm]
\noindent \textbf {\underline{CERTIFICATIONS}}
\begin{itemize}
\item{Having MS-CIT certificate}
\item{Effective Listening}
\item{Communication Foundation}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for this kind help. I tried using bbding package with /SquareShadowBottomRight but it's giving me error that undefined command.

Comment: @Vishakha I have added the second possibility by entering /SquareShadowBottomRight and everything works perfectly. I don't know what error your TeX distribution gives you. Could you please post the details of the error?